# How to move four image from one location to another location horizontally in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i have one query. i am try to develop one game like Abacus in iOS. I want to move four images, which are in sequence ,  from one location to another location horizontally in iOS. Can anyone help me please how i do this in iOS. i refer this link [How to move Object from one place to other using Animation in iphone applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860311/how-to-move-object-from-one-place-to-other-using-animation-in-iphone-application)
but using this i am able to move only one image horizontally i want to move four image how i do this.

Here's what I've tried:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject]; 
    CGPoint loc = [touch locationInView:self.view]; 
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0]; 
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(loc.x, _img.frame.origin.y, _img.frame.size.height, _img.frame.size.width); 
    [_img setFrame:rect]; 
    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far..

Comment: -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    
    UITouch * touch = [ touches anyObject];
    CGPoint loc = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(loc.x,  _img.frame.origin.y, _img.frame.size.height, _img.frame.size.width);
    
    
    
    [_img setFrame:rect];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    
}

Comment: i use this code to move image

Answer (score 1):

Put all your images in a view (lets say container view) and then move the container view